# GAE deploy error, tar_runtime_package exited with error [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

When it deploys to GAE, it starts to throw "[Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory" from "tar_runtime_package".

This is Node.js standard environment application.
FYI, I'm deploying it from Jenkins, but I cannot see any difference between deploy from local or Jenkins.

The below is the build log from GAE.  Is there any way to avoid this error?

Many thanks!

```
BUILD
Starting Step #0 - "fetcher"
Step #0 - "fetcher": Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcs-fetcher
Step #0 - "fetcher": Fetching manifest gs://staging.test-app-zivora.appspot.com/ae/96f14943-31a1-4a7b-95ac-cd1609465a70/manifest.json.
Step #0 - "fetcher": Processing 956 files.
Step #0 - "fetcher": ******************************************************
Step #0 - "fetcher": Status:                      SUCCESS
Step #0 - "fetcher": Started:                     2020-03-07T04:02:25Z
Step #0 - "fetcher": Completed:                   2020-03-07T04:03:01Z
Step #0 - "fetcher": Requested workers:    200
Step #0 - "fetcher": Actual workers:       200
Step #0 - "fetcher": Total files:          956
Step #0 - "fetcher": Total retries:        209
Step #0 - "fetcher": GCS timeouts:         209
Step #0 - "fetcher": MiB downloaded:      1276.78 MiB
Step #0 - "fetcher": MiB/s throughput:      36.42 MiB/s
Step #0 - "fetcher": Time for manifest:    937.13 ms
Step #0 - "fetcher": Total time:            36.34 s
Step #0 - "fetcher": ******************************************************
Finished Step #0 - "fetcher"
Starting Step #1 - "builder"
Step #1 - "builder": Pulling image: gcr.io/gae-runtimes/nodejs10_app_builder:nodejs10_20200223_10_19_0_RC00
Step #1 - "builder": nodejs10_20200223_10_19_0_RC00: Pulling from gae-runtimes/nodejs10_app_builder
Step #1 - "builder": 74b953307ba8: Already exists
................
Step #1 - "builder": 5a65ab630ae3: Pulling fs layer
.............
Step #1 - "builder": c2b4c17f0e50: Waiting
............
Step #1 - "builder": 5a65ab630ae3: Verifying Checksum
Step #1 - "builder": 5a65ab630ae3: Download complete
Step #1 - "builder": 5a65ab630ae3: Pull complete
Step #1 - "builder": d450843df917: Verifying Checksum
Step #1 - "builder": d450843df917: Download complete
............
Step #1 - "builder": 74fe28ea48e7: Pull complete
..............
Step #1 - "builder": Digest: sha256:0b7c289d301e2a80de53c7aa25facc9207f50f09bc51924735887c5478b06dde
Step #1 - "builder": Status: Downloaded newer image for gcr.io/gae-runtimes/nodejs10_app_builder:nodejs10_20200223_10_19_0_RC00
Step #1 - "builder": gcr.io/gae-runtimes/nodejs10_app_builder:nodejs10_20200223_10_19_0_RC00
Step #1 - "builder": 2020/03/07 04:03:12 Starting commonbuild with args [commonbuild --runtime=nodejs10 --entrypoint= --src=/workspace --config-file=/.gaeconfig/app_start.json -- ftl.par --name=asia.gcr.io/test-app-zivora/app-engine-tmp/app/ttl-2h:96f14943-31a1-4a7b-95ac-cd1609465a70 --directory=/workspace --destination=/srv --cache-repository=asia.gcr.io/test-app-zivora/app-engine-tmp/build-cache/ttl-7d --cache --additional-directory=/.gaeconfig --builder-output-path="" --base=asia.gcr.io/gae-runtimes/nodejs10:nodejs10_20200223_10_19_0_RC00].
Step #1 - "builder": 2020/03/07 04:03:12 No start command generator found for nodejs10, using default app start command "serve".
Step #1 - "builder": 2020/03/07 04:03:12 Writing configuration file "/.gaeconfig/app_start.json".
Step #1 - "builder": 2020/03/07 04:03:12 Invoking build command "ftl.par --name=asia.gcr.io/test-app-zivora/app-engine-tmp/app/ttl-2h:96f14943-31a1-4a7b-95ac-cd1609465a70 --directory=/workspace --destination=/srv --cache-repository=asia.gcr.io/test-app-zivora/app-engine-tmp/build-cache/ttl-7d --cache --additional-directory=/.gaeconfig --builder-output-path=\"\" --base=asia.gcr.io/gae-runtimes/nodejs10:nodejs10_20200223_10_19_0_RC00".
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     FTL version node-v0.17.0
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     Beginning FTL build for node
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     FTL arg passed: exposed_ports None
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     FTL arg passed: cache_repository asia.gcr.io/test-app-zivora/app-engine-tmp/build-cache/ttl-7d
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     FTL arg passed: tar_base_image_path None
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     FTL arg passed: export_cache_stats False
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     FTL arg passed: builder_output_path ""
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     FTL arg passed: name asia.gcr.io/test-app-zivora/app-engine-tmp/app/ttl-2h:96f14943-31a1-4a7b-95ac-cd1609465a70
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     FTL arg passed: ttl 168
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     FTL arg passed: global_cache False
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     FTL arg passed: cache True
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     FTL arg passed: upload True
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     FTL arg passed: sh_c_prefix False
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     FTL arg passed: fail_on_error True
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     FTL arg passed: base asia.gcr.io/gae-runtimes/nodejs10:nodejs10_20200223_10_19_0_RC00
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     FTL arg passed: output_path None
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     FTL arg passed: cache_key_version v0.17.0
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     FTL arg passed: cache_salt 
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     FTL arg passed: directory /workspace
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     FTL arg passed: entrypoint None
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     FTL arg passed: additional_directory /.gaeconfig
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     FTL arg passed: destination_path /srv
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     FTL arg passed: verbosity NOTSET
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     starting: full build
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     starting: builder initialization
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     Loading Docker credentials for repository 'asia.gcr.io/gae-runtimes/nodejs10:nodejs10_20200223_10_19_0_RC00'
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     Loading Docker credentials for repository 'asia.gcr.io/test-app-zivora/app-engine-tmp/app/ttl-2h:96f14943-31a1-4a7b-95ac-cd1609465a70'
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     builder initialization took 0 seconds
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     starting: build process for FTL image
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     starting: rm_node_modules
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     rm_node_modules rm -rf /workspace/node_modules
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     `rm_node_modules` stdout:
Step #1 - "builder": 
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     rm_node_modules took 0 seconds
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     using descriptor:package-lock.json
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     using descriptor:package.json
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     starting: checking_cached_packages_json_layer
Step #1 - "builder": DEBUG    Checking cache for cache_key 55652aee1399ef50a8240a22675a2d726c46d003d4edad884893137baec18721
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     Found cached base image: asia.gcr.io/test-app-zivora/app-engine-tmp/build-cache/ttl-7d/node-cache:55652aee1399ef50a8240a22675a2d726c46d003d4edad884893137baec18721.
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     {"architecture": "amd64", "author": "Bazel", "config": {}, "created": "2020-03-05T10:00:00Z", "history": [{"author": "Bazel", "created": "1970-01-01T00:00:00Z", "created_by": "bazel build ..."}], "os": "linux", "rootfs": {"diff_ids": ["sha256:c3c1e85def31a5a9e8168b5130d3b0d1d66634155dbb8e300e1ca043439e93ba"]}}
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     Found dependency layer for 55652aee1399ef50a8240a22675a2d726c46d003d4edad884893137baec18721 in local cache
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     Found cached dependency layer for 55652aee1399ef50a8240a22675a2d726c46d003d4edad884893137baec18721
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     {"architecture": "amd64", "author": "Bazel", "config": {}, "created": "2020-03-05T10:00:00Z", "history": [{"author": "Bazel", "created": "1970-01-01T00:00:00Z", "created_by": "bazel build ..."}], "os": "linux", "rootfs": {"diff_ids": ["sha256:c3c1e85def31a5a9e8168b5130d3b0d1d66634155dbb8e300e1ca043439e93ba"]}}
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     [CACHE][HIT] v0.17.0:NODE->55652aee1399ef50a8240a22675a2d726c46d003d4edad884893137baec18721
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     checking_cached_packages_json_layer took 1 seconds
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     starting: Building app layer
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     starting: tar_runtime_package
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     tar_runtime_package tar -pcf /tmp/tmpBZrPUI.tar --hard-dereference --transform flags=r;s,^,/srv/, --exclude *.pyc .
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     `tar_runtime_package` stdout:
Step #1 - "builder": 
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     tar_runtime_package took 12 seconds
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     starting: gzip_tar_runtime_package
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     gzip_tar_runtime_package gzip /tmp/tmpBZrPUI.tar -1
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     `gzip_tar_runtime_package` stdout:
Step #1 - "builder": 
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     gzip_tar_runtime_package took 24 seconds
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     Finished gzipping tarfile.
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     Building app layer took 43 seconds
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     starting: Building app layer
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     starting: tar_runtime_package
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     tar_runtime_package tar -pcf /tmp/tmp3CAV2A.tar --hard-dereference --transform flags=r;s,^,/.gaeconfig/, --exclude *.pyc .
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     tar_runtime_package took 0 seconds
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     Building app layer took 0 seconds
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     build process for FTL image took 45 seconds
Step #1 - "builder": INFO     full build took 45 seconds
Step #1 - "builder": ERROR    tar_runtime_package tar -pcf /tmp/tmp3CAV2A.tar --hard-dereference --transform flags=r;s,^,/.gaeconfig/, --exclude *.pyc .
Step #1 - "builder": exited with error [Errno 12] Cannot allocate memory
Step #1 - "builder": tar_runtime_package is likely not on the path
Step #1 - "builder": Traceback (most recent call last):
Step #1 - "builder":   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
Step #1 - "builder":     "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
Step #1 - "builder":   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
Step #1 - "builder":     exec code in run_globals
Step #1 - "builder":   File "/usr/local/bin/ftl.par/__main__.py", line 65, in <module>
Step #1 - "builder":   File "/usr/local/bin/ftl.par/__main__.py", line 60, in main
Step #1 - "builder":   File "/usr/local/bin/ftl.par/__main__/ftl/common/ftl_error.py", line 77, in InternalErrorHandler
Step #1 - "builder": IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '""/output'
....................
Finished Step #1 - "builder"
ERROR
ERROR: build step 1 "gcr.io/gae-runtimes/nodejs10_app_builder:nodejs10_20200223_10_19_0_RC00" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
```

Comment: Usually this happens when you are trying to deploy your application, and the instance used to deploy is running out of memory on the process. Can you change the machine type in your app.yaml to a bigger one in order to test this?

Comment: @rsalinas and how does one do that..

Comment: you have to specify a different instance_class in your app.yaml. As mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/config/appref), the default is F1, but you can change it to a bigger one.